# Rails/Adauth No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to use Adauth with rails to allow for active directory integration.

When I try to connect to the ldap server, I am getting

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it

- I used microsoft's LDP.exe tool and it connected to our PDC.
- However, when I tried to telnet to the PDC, I got a timeout.
- Advanced port scan says that port 389 is open.

My adauth yml is

```
development:
host: 10.0.0.23
 port: 389
attribute: sAMAccountName #tried uid and login
 base: dc=zzttapes1,dc=com
admin_user: cn=cgmendlatest,dc=zzttapes1, dc=com
admin_password: xxxxxxx
ssl: false   # tried as true


AdauthMappings = {
  :login => :login,
  :group_strings => :cn_groups
  }

  AdauthSearchField = [:login, :login]
```

x

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

 # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
 # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception


  helper_method :current_user



def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  end
```

Am I correct in assuming that the problem is probably at the PDC level and not the ruby code?

I am not sure if the login should be user or user@domain.com

Comment: A quick note: Try using the gem byebug and place the byebug on your specific line where you are feeling you are getting confused. Then follow your step and catch the REPL in your server. You can inspect and perform whats going on to understand and decide next flows or what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I did as rubyrider suggested and installed byebug.

I found that I had a couple of fundamental mistakes.

1. I didn't install the gem activeldap which appears to be necessary to get the authentication working
2. I was editing the wrong configuration file. I had also tried devise and the .yaml file was still in the project. I was editing that instead of the adauth.rb file in the initializers.
3. I missed some of the documentation in adauth on github pertaining to changes needed for rails 2.x (That was what gave me the clue that I was editing the wrong config file. )

I no longer get the no connection message and it appears that the rails app is authenticating against active directory.